# Javascript singleton pattern

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I don't know how to explain the issue I am facing. I had made a small snippet. Please check below:

```
var Package = {};

Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'inherit',
    {
        value: function(Parent, args)
        {
            var temp = function(){};
            temp.prototype = Parent.prototype;
            this.prototype = new temp();
            this.uber = Parent.prototype;
            this.prototype.constructor = this;
        },
        enumerable: false
    });

var Module1 = Package.Module1 = function() {
  // code;
};
Module1.prototype.method1 = function() {
};


var Module2 = Package.Module2 = function() {
  // code;
};
Module2.prototype.method2 = function() {
};


var Module3 = Package.Module3 = function() {
  // code;
};
// using custom : object.prototype.inherit
// Module3 inherit Module1 and 2;
Module3.inherit(Module1);
Module3.inherit(Module2);
Module3.prototype.method3 = function() {
};

//creating object 
var mod = new Package.Module3();
mod.method1();
mod.method2();
mod.method3();
```

Creating the mod object I can access the method1,2 and 3. But actually I want to call the methods without creating the object, like Package.Module3.method1(); how is it possible?

Comment: Does `Package.Module3` have to be a constructor function? You could just create it as an object and assign the functions to it. Or you assign an *instance* of `Module3` to `Package.Module3`. It all depends on what else you want to do with it.

Comment: right now i have. but it can be avoided.

Comment: Singleton can be object literals in javascript. You don't have great an instance of the variable using new. More information here: http://blog.anselmbradford.com/2009/04/21/object-oriented-javascript-tip-the-quintessential-singleton/

Comment: its not possible to add methods using prototype if we use.... :  var method = new function() {};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var Module3 = Package.Module3 = (function() {       
   var Module3 = function(){
       // using custom : object.prototype.inherit
       // Module3 inherit Module1 and 2;
   };
   Module3.inherit(Module1);
   Module3.inherit(Module2);
   Module3.prototype.method3 = function() {
   };
   return new Module3();
})();
```

In this case you have just one instance of `Module3` class.

*Usage*:

```
Package.Module3.method1();
Package.Module3.method2();
Package.Module3.method3();
```

Answer (score 5):

Object literal notation?

```
var Package = {
    ModuleA : {
        methodA : function(){},
        methodB : function(){}
    },
    ModuleB : {
        methodC : function(){},
        methodD : function(){}
    }
}

Package.ModuleA.methodA();
```

Comment: but my inherit method wont work. the snippet iam using function inherit(C, P) {
  var F = function(){};
  F.prototype = P.prototype;
  C.prototype = new F();
  C.uber = P.prototype;
  C.prototype.constructor = C;
}

Comment: @JaisonJustus then create an external inherit function instead: `method : ns.inheritFrom(someclass,someclass2...)`